# OOP Design for a system for reading data from different sources and send it to different destinations

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern, factory-pattern

I am working on programming a java software that will be like a middleware for gathering data from different sources then process the data and send it to different destinations.

The data sources and destinations includes: files, database, TCP, HTTP.

The user will be able to create a channels, each channel will have one data source (file reader, database reader, tcp listener) and one or many data destinations (file writer, database writer, tcp sender).

[image: channel diagram]

The application will work as following:

1. Read Channels from database.
2. For each channel create the data source and its destinations.
3. Start the data sources to read data.

What comes in my mind is:

- Sources and destinations are represented as following:
  [image]
- The channel is a container which will be injected by a source and a list of destinations. So the channel is like a **facade pattern**
- The data processor in the channel will be connected to the destinations using **observer pattern**
- At run time, when the application will load the channel list from the database, i will use the **factory pattern** to create the sources and destinations.

So, is this the best way to represents the channels, sources and destinations? I think sources and destinations have a similarities, for example, FileReader and FileWriter classes will be the same except that one will be for reading and the other for writing, is it good to represent each of them as a separate class?

Answer (score 0):

That look ok. If you look at some integration frameworks like Camel or Spring Integration, they have something very similar. They also have different types of channels (p2p async, p2p sync and pub-sub) and transformers. I mention this 2 very mature frameworks in case you want to use them rather than to write your own (I strongly suggest you to take look at Camel, as that might provide exactly what you want).

About the question of Readers/Writers, I think it's definitely better to keep them as separate classes, as otherwise it might create confusion (is this class being used as a reader or writer?) and can prevent errors (someone configuring a reader, but injecting it as a writer).

You might want to use a utility class shared between the reader and writer (or a delegate) to avoid duplicating code.